# Need to understand the concept behind SubwordTextEncoder tokenizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, transformer-model

I am currently using transformer model for my NLP task. I am looking into the transformer model [explanation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer) from Tensorflow.org.

I understood the concept behind the entire model but I am a bit stuck up at tokenization part.

Tokenization uses SubwordTextEncoder API in which we need to build vocabulary first and then for replacing sentences with the set of tokens (in order to be understood by the model), we use its .encode() function.

When I looked at its usage given on tensorflow website, I found it a bit puzzling as in how this kind of encoding may help in self-attention.

To verify my understanding about its implementation, I created my own vocabulary with 2 sentences - ['My name is xyz. I am doing experiments.'] as follows -

```
my_tokenizer = tfds.deprecated.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
   (ex for ex in ['My name is xyz. I am doing experiments.']), target_vocab_size=258)
```

After this, I tried to encode few sentences.

First,

Code -->

```
tokenized_string = my_tokenizer.encode('I am doing xyz.')
for ts in tokenized_string:
  print ('{} ----> {}'.format(ts, my_tokenizer.decode([ts])))
```

Output -->

```
8 ----> I 
6 ----> am 
5 ----> doing 
1 ----> xyz
56 ----> .
```

Another string was -

Code -->

```
tokenized_string = my_tokenizer.encode('very nice.')
for ts in tokenized_string:
  print ('{} ----> {}'.format(ts, my_tokenizer.decode([ts])))
```

Output -->

```
128 ----> v
111 ----> e
124 ----> r
131 ----> y
42 ---->  
120 ----> n
115 ----> i
109 ----> c
111 ----> e
56 ----> .
```

Can anyone tell me how this helps in achieving better self-attention? Or is this the old way of performing tokenization as I can see that this particular API is on the verge of getting deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have three option for encoding your text data:

1. based on characters (small vocabulary)
2. based on words (huge vocabulary)
3. based on subwords (vocabulary of any predefined size).

Ideally the best option is the second because every word has its semantic which could be learned by NN. But your vocabulary could be too big unless your model working in a small domain. Neural networks can efficiently work with only ~30 thousands tokens.

When you encode with characters - it is difficult for the model to efficiently find semantic pattern.

The third option is a try to create the most efficient vocabulary of the predefined size. Initially vocabulary comprise of characters and then the most frequent subwords added until you get a desirable size.

In your case - the tokenizer created vocabulary based on just few words with a relatively big vocabulary size (258). So all of your words were added to vocabulary. As a result - your vocabulary comprise of your 8 words and all characters.

When you try to decode a new sentence - decoder can not find any of new word in the vocabulary. So they were encoded by characters.

See here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_pair_encoding

Comment: Yes. I understood what it is doing. Actually, it didn't let me create vocabulary with size less than 258, the reason being it wanted to add all the characters, numbers and special characters. What I want to know is how this helps in achieving self attention as these individual characters do not have any semantic meaning as such.

Comment: @Pallavi if you don't add characters - you will not be able to encode anything other than 258 words from vocabulary. Normally your vocabulary comprise of 30000 tokens. In this case characters have some semantic meaning: e.g. the model will probably be able to predict something like 'very ', 'nic', 'e'. It is much better than 'very ', 'nic', '<unknown>'